# Android equivalent to IOS Notification Service Extension

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

In IOS, I can create a Notification Service Extension (via `UNNotificationServiceExtension`) to modify incoming notification messages (notifications that have title and body in their payload).

Is there something equivalent for that with Android? I currently use Firebase FCM to process background notifications, but the FCM library callback only works with data-only notifications, if I send a notification with title and body in the payload, the callback will not be called.

Looking around, it seems that `NotificationCompat.Extender` is what I'm looking for.

To test it I created the following implementation:

```kotlin
package com.tip_off.test

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

internal class NotificationServiceExtension : NotificationCompat.Extender {
    override fun extend(builder: NotificationCompat.Builder): NotificationCompat.Builder {

        builder.setContentTitle("KOTLIN TEST")
               .setContentText("KOTLIN HELLO")

        return builder
    }
}
```

And tried to register it as a service in the `AndroidManifest.xml` with:

```xml
<application>
  ...
  <service android:name=".MyNotificationExtenderService"
           android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
           android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.tip_off.test.NotificationServiceExtension" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  ...
</application>
```

What I was expecting is that any notification message would go through this service and replace the notification title with `"KOTLIN TEST"` and the body with `"KOTLIN HELLO"` but the code is never called.

How can I achieve this in Android?